# Как мне сделать рекурсию в быстрой сортировке?

Tags: c++, сортировка, рекурсия, быстрая-сортировка

Ниже представлен код, все никак не могу разобраться в том, как работает рекурсия, а уж тем более в быстрой сортировке. Объясните или помогите с кодом, прошу вас.

```
#include <iostream>



using namespace std;


void quicksort(int* array, int size_of_array) {
    int id_last_element = size_of_array - 1;
    int id_fist_element = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    int pivot = 0;
    cout << size_of_array << endl;
    while (id_fist_element != id_last_element)
    {
        if (flag % 2 != 0)
        {
            if (array[pivot] > array[id_last_element])
            {
                cout << array[pivot] << " change on " << array[id_last_element] << endl;
                swap(array[pivot], array[id_last_element]);
                pivot = id_last_element;
                cout << "Array: ";
                for (int k = 0; k < size_of_array; k++)
                {
                    cout << array[k] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
                id_fist_element++;
                flag++;
            }
            else {
                id_last_element--;
            }
        }
        else if (flag % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (array[pivot] < array[id_fist_element])
            {
                cout << array[pivot] << " CHANGE ON " << array[id_fist_element] << endl;
                swap(array[pivot], array[id_fist_element]);
                pivot = id_fist_element;
                for (int k = 0; k < size_of_array; k++)
                {
                    cout << array[k] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
                id_last_element--;
                flag++;
            }
            else {
                id_fist_element++;
            }
        }
    }
    
}



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int array_1[10] = { 5,3,8,2,6,9,1,7,4,10 };

    int array_size = end(array_1) - begin(array_1);


    cout << "Unsorted array:";
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        cout << array_1[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    quicksort(array_1, array_size);


    cout << "result is:" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
    {
        cout << array_1[j] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Код быстрой сортировки не секретный, его легко найти.